# Two weblogic for Oracle Webcenter content content (WCC aka UCM) & webcenter sites (WCS) installation

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, webcenter, wcs, oracle-ucm

I intend to use two weblogic for WCC & WCS respectively i.e. Two middlewares paths. will there be any difficulaties/challeneges i may face ? if there is any reference links for the same.

weblogic version 10.3.6
WCC,WCS version 11.1.8

Answer (score 1):

You should be ok at a minimum to use separate domains for WCC and WCS (having them share a domain does cause issues). Using two entirely separate middleware paths may be overkill, but is unlikely to cause any issues.

Phil